# USB to USB Back-Side Device Communications

Tags: usb

I wonder, if two USB devices are connected to a single computer, may they correspond without any interaction with the host computer?  I understand the need to an active component in the network.  What is at issue is any need for action by the host in order that intercommunication between connected devices may ensue.

---

Edit (from the comments):

I should like to plug into a single computer two thumb devices (USB capable devices) and to have those two devices find each other on their respective USB connectors (ports?) without necessitating any action on the part of the host CPU. I understand that I might write software that executes upon the host, and so mitigate such inter-thumb device communications. Yet, is such mitigating software necessary?

Comment: "_may they correspond without any interaction with the host computer_" - no... can you expand on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Dear Attie:
Thank you for the kind and rather prompt response.
I should like to plug into a single computer two thumb devices (usb capable devices) and to have those two devices find each other on their respective usb connectors (ports?) without necessitating any action on the part of the host CPU.  I understand that I might write software that executes upon the host, and so mitigate such inter-thumb device communications.  Yet, is such mitigating software necessary?

Comment: @wrb as explained in my answer, that is completely impossible. You need the host. USB is not able to do device-device communications itself.

Answer (score 5):

> I wonder, if two USB devices are connected to a single computer, may they correspond without any interaction with the host computer?

No. In USB, all information flows through the host, and devices cannot talk to each other. There's no way for a USB hub to route signal from a device anywhere but host-wards; on USB, all devices take turns (controlled by host and hub) to talk, and the data is sent upstream. Because no two devices *can* be active at the same time, there's no way to send data directly from one to the other.

That's simply how USB was designed from the get-go. It would seem to me it fits what USB is used for quite well: computer peripherals without need for DMA.

So, what you'd need to implement for that is software running on the host PC that shuffles the data from one device to the other. No shortcuts are possible.

(Do note that the Thunderbolt mode you sometimes find on USB C, and USB 4, can encapsulate PCIe which theoretically could do device-device DMA, but that has little to do with "USB devices"; it's essentially just a different protocol embedded in USB, and would by design in all imaginable configurations I'm aware of still go through the host computer's PCIe root complex.)

Comment: Excellent answer.  Thank you for the detail.  Just what I need to know.